# Old dojo version loading after Domino 9.0.1 FP3 upgrade

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-domino

We are trying to upgrade from `8.5.3` to `9.0.1 FP3`. However, after the Domino update, some of my dojo functionality is not working. I am VERY new to xPages/dojo and this code was written by another developer that was much more experienced with xPages that I.

In production, when then page loads:

> GET servername/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/i18n.js 200 OK 172ms dojo.js (line 14)
>   GET servername/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dijit/nls/loading.js 200 OK 156ms dojo.js (line 14)
>   GET servername/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dijit/nls/common.js 200 OK 172ms   dojo.js (line 14)
>   GET servername/services/rdts/rstdocs.n...g-view&empids=CHGS-99WQKW&board=my&disptype=json 200 OK 2.22s

All in bold black (firebug) and seem to all be loaded just fine.

On our development server, it has the same design same configurations. The only thing that is different is the the server is now on Domino 9.0.1 FP3. I get this:

> GET servername/domjs/dojo-1.5.2/ibm/xsp/widget/layout/xspClientDojo.js 404 Not Found 750ms dojo.js (line 14)
>   Error: Could not load 'ibm.xsp.widget.layout.xspClientDojo'; last tried '../ibm/xsp/widget/layout/xspClientDojo.js'dojo.js (line 14, col 6081)
>   GET servername/domjs/dojo-1.5.2/dojox/grid/LazyTreeGrid.js 404 Not Found 344ms  dojo.js (line 14)
>   GET servername/domjs/dojo-1.5.2/dijit/tree/ForestStoreModel.js 304 Not Modified 334ms   dojo.js (line 14)
>   Error: Could not load 'dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid'; last tried '../dojo/grid/LazyTreeGrid.js

Why is dojo not loading what the dojo default id for `9.0.1`? I double checked the `.xsp` properties page and it is not set to use anything but default dojo. I think there is a way to change the version of dojo in the actual code but I do not know how to do that so I am not sure what to look for. Is there some text string I could do a search on? Also, I am not sure it will find anything because if it did it seems like it would be the same in production and development because it is the same design. Any idea? I am happy to supply more information if someone can tell me what information is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `domjs/dojo` in your database in Designer. It is very likely that you'll find a line like

```
xsp.client.script.dojo.path=/domjs/dojo-1.5.2
```

in Application Configuration / Xsp Properties / Source tab or a similar setting in a theme or in XPage's [properties](http://xcellerant.net/2014/09/18/modifying-an-xsp-property-fo-a-single-xpage/).

Remove this line and Domino will use the default Dojo version.

Check also folder data/properties on Domino server if there is a file `xsp.properties` with an entry like

```
xsp.client.script.dojo.version=1.5.2
```

and remove such a line too.